# How to draw this picture : a phase portrait in LATEX

Tags: diagrams

Please I need some help.
How can I draw this picture on Latex ?
Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: Welcome! Can you show any attempts you've made so far? Which graphics package(s) do you use?

Comment: I do not master latex , in fact I have only discovered it a few days ago. So my skills are limited. I use Package Tikz.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `pstricks`. For the `auto-pst-pdf` package to work, launch pdflatex with the `--enable-write18` switch, under MiKTeX, `shell-escape` for TeX Live or CMacTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt,,section]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \psset{unit=3cm}
    \psaxes[yAxis=false, labels=none, ticksize=2.5pt -2.5pt]{-}(0,0)(-1.4,0)(1.4, 0)
    \uput[d](-1,0){$ x₀ $}\uput[d](1,0){$ x₀ $}
    \uput[d](0,0){$ O $}
    \psset{ArrowInside=-v, veearrowangle=40, veearrowlength=6pt, veearrowlinewidth=0.8pt,}
    \psline[ArrowInsidePos=0.45]{-}(-1,0)(0, 0)
    \psline[ArrowInsidePos=0.6]{-}(0, 0)(1,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how can I launch pdflatex with the --enable-write18 switch under Miktek ?

Comment: The way depends on your editor. Which do you use?